# AWS Load Balancer & BlueHost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, bluehost

Currently my domain name `adthrone.com` is pointed to ec2 instance ip `5x.xx.xx.xx`

That domain result is HTTP

So I created a load balancer with this link https://adthrone-loadbalancer-1188159040.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/

Now, Is that even possible to change the DNS pointing of

`5x.xx.xx.xx`

to this

https://adthrone-loadbalancer-1188159040.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/

I tried to contact my DNS Provider BlueHost. But they seems do not want to change it. Because on my bluehost screen. If I manually change it. From `EC2 IP` to `Load Balancer` there is an error that the link is not applicable.

The load balancer is working fine, it has only mixed content that needed to fix. But the issue is that possible to change the DNS pointing from IP to Link?

Answer (score 1):

Use a CNAME record instead. You can put `adthrone-loadbalancer-1188159040.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` in the value field of the CNAME record.

Comment: Hello just to clarify. I'll leave my @ host point to `IP` and add record on CNAME that the pointings is Load Balancer?

Comment: It turns out that CNAME can't be used at the apex of a domain, so I recommend creating a CNAME subdomain `www.adthrone.com` which points to `adthrone-loadbalancer-1188159040.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`. Then add a 301 redirection from `adthrone.com` to `www.adthrone.com`.

Comment: You mean, on my blue host I need to add on my CNAME with www and load balancer. Since my @Host record `adthrone.com` redirects to `5x.xxx.xxx.xx` ec2 instance, I need to change my apache vhost  port 80 to `redirect permanent / https://www.adthrone.com` ?

Comment: Yes, maybe you can do the redirection part in bluehost. I found this on the web. https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/182